# Amplify is not converting my hosted UI code to access token

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have an angular project
I added Amplify and want to use AWS Cognito as my auth provider.

When using HostedUi login I'm redirected to my site like:
http://localhost:4200/?code=3f983d7f-24e3-4e34-a42e-fe812f72ee88

But no access token is located in my local storage.

I defined these keys in my configuration file:

```
cognito: {
    region : 'eu-west-1',
    userPoolId: 'eu-west-1_xxxxxxx',
    userPoolWebClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    responseType: 'code',
    scope : ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid','aws.cognito.signin.user.admin']
  }

and configure amplify like this 
    Auth.configure({
      Auth: environment.cognito,
    });
```

Any idea what I'm missing in order to get the access token automatically set in the local storage?

Thank you :-)